# Make Intellij IDE run the Kotlin/Java annotation processing when changing Kotlin source files

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, kotlin

Recently I have started using Kotlin v1.2 with Intellij IDEA v2017.3.

I implemented an annotation processor in Kotlin, which writes a resource file under META-INF, when a class is annotated with the supported annotation type.

I can see that the annotation processor is working with another Maven project, which is using the implementation as a dependency. If I run `mvn clean compile`, the file under META-INF is generated correctly in **target/classes/META-INF**.

My problem is that Intellij does not start the annotation processor when a source file is changed. For example, if I rename the annotated Kotlin class. The resource file is not regenerated or updated. (I haven't seen the annotation processor working yet from Intellij...)

I also enabled annotation processing and configured "obtain processors from project classpath" within the IDE like described [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-annotation-processing.html).

I imported the project as a Maven project here is my pom.xml - like I said: It is working when building with Maven:

```
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

   <groupId>org.example</groupId>
   <artifactId>usage</artifactId>
   <version>1</version>

   <properties>
     <kotlin.version>1.2.0</kotlin.version>
   </properties>

   <build>
     <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/kotlin</sourceDirectory>
     <testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/kotlin</testSourceDirectory>

     <plugins>
       <plugin>
         <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
         <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
         <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
         <configuration>
           <jvmTarget>1.8</jvmTarget>
         </configuration>
         <executions>
           <execution>
             <id>kapt</id>
             <phase>generate-sources</phase>
             <goals>
               <goal>kapt</goal>
             </goals>
             <configuration>
               <sourceDirs>
                 <sourceDir>src/main/kotlin</sourceDir>
               </sourceDirs>
               <annotationProcessors>
                 <annotationProcessor>org.example.MyProcessor</annotationProcessor>
               </annotationProcessors>
             </configuration>
           </execution>
           <execution>
             <id>compile</id>
             <phase>compile</phase>
             <goals>
               <goal>compile</goal>
             </goals>
           </execution>
           <execution>
             <id>test-compile</id>
             <phase>test-compile</phase>
             <goals>
               <goal>test-compile</goal>
             </goals>
           </execution>
         </executions>
       </plugin>
     </plugins>
   </build>

   <dependencies>
     <dependency>
       <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
       <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib</artifactId>
       <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
     </dependency>

     <!-- Dependency containing the annotation processor -->
     <dependency>
       <groupId>org.example</groupId>
       <artifactId>processor</artifactId>
       <version>1</version>
     </dependency>

     <!-- Test -->
     <dependency>
       <groupId>junit</groupId>
       <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
       <version>4.12</version>
       <scope>test</scope>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
       <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
       <artifactId>kotlin-test</artifactId>
       <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
       <scope>test</scope>
     </dependency>
   </dependencies>
 </project>
```

Comment: Annotation processor is started on compile/build. Have you tried to run build after changing file? Does it work this way?

Comment: When I delete the whole target folder or just META-INF folder under target/classes, a "Build Module" or "Maven -> Generate Sources and Update Folders" works sometimes, but not reliable. If the generated file under META-INF already exists and I perform one of those actions, the file is not regenerated.